# Polymorphism and operator overloading confusion in c++

Tags: c++

I don't know how to read ageMonth with  `>>` operator I defined up there.I have to create a dynamic object `gos=new Baby` but when I do that I don't know the name of the object so I cant pass it to the >> operator.

```
class Human{
public:
    virtual void write();
};

class Baby:public Human{
int ageMonth;
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is,Human* ref);
    void write(){cout<<"Average mass of the baby: "<<(ageMonth+9)/2<<endl;
    }
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is,Human* ref){
is>>ref->ageMonth;  //This gives error
return is;
}


int main(){
char ch;
Insan* gos;
cout<<"Enter B for baby , C for children: "<<endl;
cin>>ch;
if(ch=='B'){
    gos=new Baby;
    cout<<"Enter the age of the baby as month "<<endl;
    cin>>gos; //gives error
    gos->write();
```

Comment: I know it's not easy to write in a foreign language (not being a native speaker myself), but please, try to keep your identifiers in English. It makes understanding your source MUCH easier.

Comment: Please reduce your program to a bare minimum, then copy and paste it to the question as a single block of code. Indicate which specific errors you are getting (copy and paste unedited error messages). Make sure that the code you post is the code you compile.

Answer (score 0):

**Work on references, not pointers. *Define* the operator.**

```
class Baby:public Human{
    // ...
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Baby* ref);
```

This only says, "there is some `operator>>` function *defined elsewhere* that I allow to operate on (pointers to) `Baby` objects". You still have to *define* that function.

Then, this doesn't really work on *pointers*. You need an *existing* object to operate on, setting its member variables with what you read from input. That is why the `operator>>` needs to be `friend`: It needs access to the members.

Your line `Baby * gos;` does not create an object to work on, it just creates a pointer (that points nowhere).

So define the function to operate on a *reference*, not pointer.

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream & is, Baby & ref);
```

Then *define* the function:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Baby & ref)
{
    cin >> ref.ageMonth;
    // ...
}
```

Then you should be able to use it:

```
Baby gos; // actually creating the object
// ...
cin >> gos;
```

Alternatively, if you *have* to work with dynamic memory:

```
Baby * gos = new Baby();
// ...
cin >> *gos;
```

Consider using [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this fragment

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Human* ref){
is>>ref->ageMonth;  //This gives error
return is;
```

The first problem is that you need to pass a reference, not a pointer.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Human& ref){
```

It is not, strictly speaking, an error to use a pointer here, just a bad practice that can easily lead to errors. So please use a reference.

The second, bigger, problem is that you have a `Human` and trying to use `ageMonth` which `Human` doesn't have.

If you know you have a `Baby`, just say that:

```
 istream& operator>>(istream& is, Baby& ref){
```

If you don't know which kind of `Human` you have, you can only use things that are common to all `Human`s.